# bash stdout followed by prompt on same line

Tags: bash

In bash, some commands put their stdout BEFORE the command prompt and on the SAME line. For example:

```
$ printf message
message$ 
$ gettext -d gtk20 File
Fichier$
```

I want the stdout on a dedicated line with the command prompt on the NEXT line. I could precede with 'echo' and wrap in back ticks like this, but I wonder if there is a better way (an arg that can be always/often used, etc):

```
$ echo `printf message`
message
$
$ echo `gettext -d gtk20 File`
Fichier
$
```

Comment: "some commands put their stdout BEFORE the command prompt and on the SAME line" - it sounds like you may have a mistaken impression of where all this output is coming from. The standard output from the command (`message` in your first example) comes from the command itself, but the prompt comes from the shell. The command has _nothing_ to do with printing out the prompt.

Comment: @DavidZ
is there an option in preferences in Linux to change how bash displays printf?

Comment: @john That might be a good thing to ask as a separate question, either here or on [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `; printf "\n"` or `; echo` after your command.  The issue is that your output does not end with a newline.

You could also just inject the command output into a single `printf "%s\n"` command.

Comment: yes. thanks. Here's the complex (real world) case (on Ubuntu) that this fixes:

$ printf "`ngettext -d gtk20 'Opening %d Item' 'Opening %d Items' 5`" 5 && echo
Ouverture de 5 éléments
$

Answer (score 2):

You can set your prompt to handle this for you automatically.

```
PS1='$(printf "%$(($(tput cols)-1))s\r")\u@\h [\w]\$ '
```

From [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/97503/bash-how-to-know-if-the-last-commands-output-ends-with-a-newline-or-not) on Server Fault.

It prints enough spaces to wrap around the end of the line then a carriage return (`\r`) to return to the first column. You can customize what it displays after that the same way you normally would.